# ExtJS mode for Emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, ide, eclipse-plugin, extjs

I got used to Emacs, and it's JavaScript modes are quite modest, as far as I can tell. I'm about to do some serious ExtJS coding, and I'd like to use Emacs. Spket plugin available in Eclipse is great, but is there any ExtJS Emacs mode available? After thorough Google querying, I reckon that chances are very slim, but... hey... just asking...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a JavaScript programmer, but I seem to recall people being excited when Steve Yegge whipped up [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/), a JavaScript mode for emacs.

Would that do?

Comment: Well, it still modest. I think I'll stick to Aptana/Eclipse, since it has ExtJS support, while having Emacs keybindings enabled. Thanks for suggestion, though... I'll give js2-mode a try, since it's highly customisable!

Comment: What is your definition of "modest". js2-mode is not a modest mode by any of my definitions.

Comment: Well... apart from lack of ExtJS (Sencha) library, I find it a bit cumbersome... in my opinion, nxhtml is better (but still has no ExtJS support). Is it at all possible? Can I just point to ExtJS sources and get autocomplete/syntax highlight feature?